# Onload timer reset or restart

Tags: javascript, loops, onload

Is there any way I can reset the time of this onload?

```
function auto(){
  setInterval(slide, 5000);
}
window.onload = auto;
```

In my case, when I change slides manually through the checkboxes, the timer does not reset and basically passes the chosen slide quickly, because the counter did not reset along with the slide() function.

I use this for listerning the slides indexs (Checkboxes), and reload slideshow script.

```
function check(input) {
    //set checked of clicked object
  slideContador = input.name;
  slide();
}

function slide() {
  if(slideContador >= slideTamanho) {
    slideContador = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('slide-link').href = slideLink[slideContador];  
  document.getElementById('slide-img').src = slideImg[slideContador];
  document.getElementById('slideshow-bg').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + slideFundo[slideContador] + "')";
//Desmarca checkboxes
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("rounded-checkbox");
        for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
            //uncheck all
            if(checkboxes[i].checked == true)
            {
                checkboxes[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
var element = document.getElementsByName(slideContador)[0];
element.checked = true;
//Almenta o contador
slideContador++;
}
```

Comment: Hi.  You really need to include more information about what you are doing.  I assume you have a carousel of some sort, but you say "when I change slides manually through the checkboxes" .... how is that happening?  If you have some javascript code that is being called to manually step through slides, then there's every chance you can reset a variable or interval there.  But at this point, you really haven't provided enough information about your page for someone to be able to assist

Comment: Sorry for that, I've edited the post. It just doesn't include the arrays containing the information of the images, I think it's not necessary because they can be any image.

Comment: onload default if slide method is executing, where you are setting the default values for slideContador ,  slideTamanho variables ?

Comment: so cancel the timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use clearInterval to remove the timer.

```js
let timer = null
function auto(shouldSlide){
  if (timer) window.clearInterval(timer);
  timer = window.setInterval(slide, 5000);
  if (shouldSlide) slide();
}
window.addEventListener('load', function() { auto(); });

function check(input) {
  slideContador = input.name;
  auto(true);
}
```

Comment: It works. But I couldn't understand how the "timer" variable works. Can you explain to me please?

Comment: Read the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval